# Populate a column in MySQL with column value from another table

Tags: mysql, database, join, insert, sql-update

I am trying to do something in SQL that I imagined would be very basic, but I absolutely cannot seem to figure it out.

I have 2 tables :

Provinces ->

```
 id                                  |   name     |  pCode |  country_id  | cCode
78840113-a0e5-11e4-8237-de7fe3f523cf |  Alabama   | AL     | 1228         |
7884030c-a0e5-11e4-8237-de7fe3f523cf |  Alaska    | AK     | 1228         |
788403ea-a0e5-11e4-8237-de7fe3f523cf |  Arizona   | AZ     | 1228         |
788404a2-a0e5-11e4-8237-de7fe3f523cf |  Arkansas  | AR     | 1228         |
```

and Countries ->

```
iso_code  | name                   | country_id
AD        | Andorra                | 1005           
AE        | United Arab Emirates   | 1225           
AF        | Afghanistan            | 1001           
AG        | Antigua and Barbuda    | 1009
```

I just want to have the cCode column in Provinces populated with the appropriate iso_code (if country_id in provinces and countries are the same).

I have tried so many things it isn't even writing my code here, I don't even know which direction is the correct way to go for this (join, insert, update??). I am completely stuck please help me!

Comment: So, based on your sample data, no update since there are no matching country_id?

Comment: This is just a subset of the data.

Answer (score 6):

If you are really using Mysql:

```
update Provinces p
inner join countries c on
    p.country_id = c.country_id
set p.cCode = c.iso_code
```

Comment: Note that using an INNER JOIN will update only the records with matching country_id; it won't touch any others. I.e. it won't clear Provinces.cCode values for non-matching records.

Comment: He just wants to have the cCode column in Provinces populated with the appropriate iso_code (if country_id in provinces and countries are the same).

Comment: When I try this I get Error Code 1175: You are using sage update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.     Is it safe for me to turn off safe mode?  I'm not sure what the consequences will be.

Comment: Because of your safe mode option, you are not able to update/delete without the primary key on where clause. You'll not be able to make this update that you want with safe mode on and this query is not gonna do anything that's not expected. So you could set it off just to execute this update and later turn it on again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`UPDATE...JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) syntax here:

```
UPDATE provinces JOIN countries USING (country_id)
  SET provinces.cCode=countries.iso_code
```

Comment: As with the above answer, When I try this I get Error Code 1175: You are using sage update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.     Is it safe for me to turn off safe mode?  I'm not sure what the consequences will be.

Comment: @user1795370 try `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`